# Is there a way to check the email domain validity with node.js Eg, gmail.com is valid form, if user enter egmail.com or something like that,

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, email-validation

I am working with React.js and Express.js/Node.js. I am using nodemailer for sending emails. But I have received a lot of emails with the wrong domains like instead of **abc@gmail.com**, I am receiving **abc@egmail.com**, **abc@gmial.com**, etc. Somebody can help me to fix it on the client-side or server-side.

```
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: config.get("USER"),
    pass: config.get("PASS"),
  },
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Send a _"Please confirm your address by clicking on this link"_ mail to the mail address. If the address is valid they will click the link. If not... -> trash can

Comment: You can create a new step in email validation. A clickable link sent to email address. It only confirms that's a "real" e-mail recipient.  Said that, be aware of services like https://temp-mail.org/ that creates a temporary mail box. It will give you the same result of sent email to wrong domains.

Comment: Or you could have a list of common email domains and check if the email given to you is among them. `let among = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com", "hotmail.com"...].includes(user.email.split("@")[1])`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from sending an actual email message asking the recipient to click a link to confirm his or her email address - like others suggested in the comments - you may want to check the email using an [email verification service](https://verifalia.com/) like our Verifalia, which checks whether an email address points to a real, deliverable mailbox in seconds, without sending any message at all.

Since you have mentioned you would like your solution to work in either React and/or Node.js, the great news is that we offer a ready-made JavaScript integration library which covers both:

- Source: https://github.com/verifalia/verifalia-js-sdk
- Npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/verifalia

**Node.js**

```js
const { VerifaliaRestClient } = require('verifalia');

// ...

const verifalia = new VerifaliaRestClient({ /* configuration */ });

// ...

verifalia
    .emailValidations
    .submit('batman@gmail.com', true)
    .then(validation => {
        // At this point the address has been validated: let's print
        // its email validation result to the console.

        const entry = validation.entries[0];
        console.log(entry.inputData, entry.classification, entry.status);

        // Prints out something like:
        // batman@gmail.com Deliverable Success
    });
```

**React / Angular / Vue / ... / any ES module bundler**

```js
import { VerifaliaRestClient } from 'verifalia';

// ...

const verifalia = new VerifaliaRestClient({ /* configuration */ });

// Alternative await syntax (one could still use the promise-based syntax mentioned above)

const validation = await verifalia
    .emailValidations
    .submit('batman@gmail.com', true);

// At this point the address has been validated: let's print
// its email validation result to the console.

const entry = validation.entries[0];
console.log(entry.inputData, entry.classification, entry.status);

// Prints out something like:
// batman@gmail.com Deliverable Success
```

We also offer a turn-key JavaScript widget you can put on any web page, which *automagically* turns every `<input type="email" />` field on a fully Verifalia-powered validated email field. You may want to check it out, even if I believe it may not apply to your case: https://www.npmjs.com/package/verifalia-widget

---

Disclaimer: I am the CTO of Verifalia.